# How to get the collection of items filtered out from the DataView

Tags: c#, winforms, filtering, dataview

I needs to get the collection of items which are filtered out from the view by using the RowFilter in DataView.

I can get the overall records from the DataView by using the following query.

```
 allRecords= (data as DataView).Table.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
```

I need only the filtererd records collection from the DataView. How can I achive this.
EX: if a table as the recorda a, b, c, d
And then filter is applied to display only a in the view. Now I needs to get the items which are not in view (b, c and d). Help me on this to solve the problem.

Comment: You can use [Linq Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) between the two collections to get the difference.

Comment: I have try to use the Except method but there is no difference from the output. 
`var table = (data as DataView).ToTable().AsEnumerable();
var allTable = (data as DataView).Table.AsEnumerable();
filteredRecords = allTable.Except(table).AsQueryable();`

Comment: You need to compare against a filtered table, not the same exact table.

Comment: Here the table which i have mentioned is the filtered table(which contains only 100 rows) whereas the allTable contains all the records (225 rows).

Comment: Its working by adding the Default DataRowComparer `allTable.Except(table, DataRowComparer.Default)`, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will filter the data table (assuming your column name is recorda)

```
 (data as DataView).DefaultView.RowFilter = "recorda='a'";
```

And this will then call "ToTable()" which makes a table out of the filtered view, rather than just Table which is a reference to the full unfiltered table.

```
allRecords= (data as DataView).ToTable()
```

Comment: I don't able to assign the DefaultView property from the DataView `(data as DataView).DefaultView = "recorda='a'";` Is there I missed anything?